# Anyway to pretty print json data in CMDER or CMD terminal in a way that's searchable / drillable

Tags: cmd, terminal, cmder

Currently I use CMDER for terminal in Windows.  When I console.log out an object it looks like this:

ex: `console.log(data)`

[image: CMDER Example]

Just a plain text non-interactive display of the data.

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the output to be more like Firefox or Chrome in the console log where it's interactive (you can drill down into the object / array and you can search / filter through it).

Here is an example of how Firefox let's you interact and search the json data, which is extremely useful.

[image: Firefox Console Logs]

Would make debugging logs much easier.